# Transportrule -> Text Pattern Regex to capture domain and subdomain

Tags: email, regex, spam-prevention, exchange-2010

I'm running an On-Premise Exchange 2010 with the following Transportrule checking for Text Pattern on Sender Address:

```
^.+@(?=.*microsoft)(?=.*.com).*$
```

Above Regex gets captured if "microsoft" is present either as a domain or subdomain, and ends with ".com".
If I want I can omit ".com" all together and leave it as ".*." in case the address in question uses multiple top level domains for some reason...

So what is wrong with this?
Using tools like Regex Hero tells me that the above syntax should work, but when I add it to my Transportrule it doesn't seem to do as told.

Answer (score 1):

After further digging I have found out that Exchange doesn't support Regular Expressions totally, so I tried scrapping everything and try rebuilding it with their [limited syntax](http://blog.chrislehr.com/2014/11/using-regular-expressions-in-exchange.html):

```
(.*\W)(@*)microsoft(\W)(.*com)$
```

This captures the following addresses:

- microsoft.com
- microsoft-test.com
- microsoft.test.com
- test-microsoft.com
- test.microsoft.com

I'm aware that the 2nd and 3rd matches would be seen as phising, but unfortunately there are a couple senders I trust that use that kind of pattern...

Comment: It's an actual solution, using this right now and is working, if anyone else has alternatives that work as a Transport Rule with the "Regular Expression" Exchange supports, I'm welcome to check them out, rather accept someone elses answer than my own.